# Element property is undefined in IE 9

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-9

In JavaScript I am reading HTML elements as shown below code.

```
myTableElements = document.getElementsByTagName("table");

for(var i = 0; i < myTableElements.length; i++) {  
   // The following line fails as `myTableElements[i].name` is undefined  
   if (myTableElements[i].name == tGovTabName)
     //do something
 }
```

The same code works fine in IE 7 and IE 8, but not in IE 9.  I couldn't find any clue by observing the HTML code in both the browsers IE8 and IE9.

Can anyone spot the problem?

Comment: It's not Java, it's JavaScript...

Comment: I used myTableElements[i].getAttribute("name"). It worked. Thanks to all those who replied.

Comment: @pratima: It's your call, but your HTML is still invalid.

Comment: @AndyE: Then how should I handle it? I am a newbie. Doesn't have much knowledge in JS,HTML

Comment: @pratima: that depends on your HTML.  If your tables don't already have `id` attributes, then use those instead.  Otherwise, you could use `data-` attributes, which would make your HTML valid for HTML5 validators.  See http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/.

Answer (score 2):

Since [table elements do not have a name attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html), I wouldn't expect them to have a name property, so it shouldn't be defined and this is expected behaviour.

Comment: +1, they finally removed the behaviour of adding all attributes as expando properties in IE 9, which is why it works in the earlier browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The `<table>` tag in HTML doesnt have a name attribute .....

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#edef-TABLE

Can you not use ID ?